# webpack configuration: pixi.js imported in app.js generates an over 2MB distribution file

Tags: javascript, webpack, pixi.js

Creating a pixi.js component based on pixi.js and es6 modules.
In my app.js I am importing everything from pixi.js:
`import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';`
 I am also transpiling the code with babel:

```
rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

which as a result generates a large file. If I exclude pixi.js from app.js - the file is 700KB only.

Comment: You can create a separated bundle for the libs in your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pixi.js (unminified) is 1.3MB, so what do you expect? If you want a smaller filesize you have to use a minification plugin for webpack, like uglify.

Comment: my guess was that pixi.js file gets transpiled by babel also and that is the reason the filesize is so large. I thought, if I could somehow include pixi.js lib in the distribution file without transpiling - file size would be smaller.

Comment: It's incredible, but minified and uglified version of my component with pixi.js lib is only 632kB! I used `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` to uglify and set the mode to `production`